# what is gnome-online-miners?

Tags: gnome, libraries

I got a crash at `/usr/lib/gnome-online-miners/gom-media-server-miner` and I wonder.. What on Earth is it mining?

My GoogleFu resulted only in info it [provides a set of crawlers that go through your online content and index them locally in Tracker. It has miners for Facebook, Flickr, Google, ownCloud and SkyDrive.](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeOnlineMiners)

Could someone tell me what exactly is it doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as your search result said. If you add any of those accounts in *Online Accounts* settings, while using GNOME, the `gnome-online-miners` miners will scan those services for your data, and index it in the local `tracker` database, so that when you search for data in GNOME shell, those results will appear.

Comment: Ok, so I can e.g synchronize my gnome calendar with Facebook or something like that?

Comment: I don't know if there's a calendar back-end for Facebook. And I don't think it would go through the tracker miners if so. This is more like finding your photos in Facebook, docs in Google, etc… Calendars/Contacts are done via a different process.